# Is there a function whose second derivative is the inverse square of itself?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Namely, is there a function $f(x)$ that satisfies

$$\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{(f(x))^2}$$

I've been messing with an overly simplified physical system in which a body has a gravitational attraction towards another body much more massive (allowing me to assume that the second body doesn't move), and I got the following differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{Gm}{(x(t))^2}$$

That got me wondering if such differential equation has a known solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**hint**

$$y'' = \frac{1}{y^2} \implies$$

$$y'y''=\frac{y'}{y^2} \implies$$

$$\frac{y'^2}{2}= -\frac 1y +C$$

In the particular case $ C=0 $, we have

$$y'=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{-y}}$$
and

$$\frac 23(-y)^\frac 32=-x\sqrt{2}$$

From here, we can see that the function $$Y:x\mapsto x^{\frac 23}$$
satisfies
$$Y'=\frac 23x^{-\frac 13} \; \text { and }\;Y''=-\frac 29x^{-\frac 43}$$
$$=\frac{K}{Y^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve
$$f''(x) = \frac{1}{(f(x))^2}$$ Consider instead $x(f)$ and the equation is
$$-\frac {x''(f)} {[x'(f)]^3}=\frac 1{f^2}$$ Reduction of order $p=x'(f)$ gives

$$-\frac {p'}{p^3}=\frac 1{f^2}\implies p=\frac{\sqrt{f}}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{c_1 f-1}}$$
$$x(f)=c_2+\frac{\log \left(c_1\sqrt{f}+\sqrt{c_1} \sqrt{c_1f -1}\right)}{\sqrt{2}   c_1^{3/2}}+\frac{\sqrt{f} \sqrt{c_1f -1}}{\sqrt{2} c_1}$$

Now the problem is to inverse $x(f)$.